# Can't access user model in middleware

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I created a custom middleware for checking if request is submitted by user who owns the resource or owned by admin.

```
Route::middleware(['web', 'selforadmin'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('users/update-account/{id}', 'UsersController@UpdateAccount');
    Route::post('users/update-email/{id}', 'UsersController@UpdateEmail');
    Route::post('users/update-password/{id}', 'UsersController@UpdatePassword');
});
```

and then the middleware handler:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    print_r($request->all());
    print_r($request->user());

    dd();

    return $next($request);
}
```

But I don't know why user model is not accessible here. I read that request needs to pass from web middleware first so I did but still can't access this middleware.

**It gives null on $request->user() or Auth::user()**

**I am using Laravel 5.4**

EDIT:

**Middleware is being called as I see other inputs. Only Auth is empty. And User is logged.**

Comment: Did you tried `\Aith::user()` or `auth()->user()` ??

Comment: I don't need Auth facade in middleware. According to docs request should have user model but yes I have tried and it gives null.

Comment: What about `auth()->id()` ? and are you using laravel auto generated auth or a custom one ?

Comment: Default Laravel auth. Though I moved User to different namespace but that shouldn't be a problem since I updated that in authconfig already.

Comment: Everything else is working fine. Its just this middleware I don't have access to user model.

Comment: When is your middleware called?

Comment: SelfOrAdmin is the class name and its registered in middleware array as selforadmin. Just to clear things, it shows other request variables. Just Auth is null and user is logged in as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access using models directly in middleware. You need to define a `terminate` method in your middleware to perform some processing after response has been sent to browser.

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    // Your code ...
}
```

Comment: I am following this doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#middleware-parameters Says that I can access user model for checking roles.

Answer (score 0):

If user is not logged in it will always return null.

There are two solution for this.

First is, check if **$request->user()** is not null.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if($request->user())
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // do otherwise
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Second is, add **auth** middleware before your middleware to assure that only logged in users are allowed.

```
Route::middleware(['web', 'auth', 'selforadmin'])->group(function () {
    // .....
}
```

Comment: Used is logged in.